# How to add line return in invoice description line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, intuit-partner-platform

I am using the Intuit IPP QBD v3 API and looking to put line breaks in text that will be in the invoice detail line description. I've tried putting in the \n and \r\n to no avail...the lines do not show being split when you view the invoice in Quickbooks Desktop after import. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Did you escape the \n? If that too does not work then it is probably not supported.

Comment: Although this is not related to your line issue, it is related to you using QBD V3. I also wanted to make sure you saw this blog post about QBD access being discontinued.
https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/09/08/timeline-to-discontinue-the-quickbooks-desktop-rest-api